# replace exact string in another string

Tags: php, regex

I have array of vars

```
array(2) {  
  ["M"]=>
  string(3) "500"
  ["MA"]=>
  string(3) "200"
}
```

AND strings "1000-M", "1000-MA", "1000+MA-M", "MA/2", "M*MA+100"

And I need to replace M with value 500, and MA with value 200. When I use str_replace it works but only for M, because it still match with first var M

Thanks for help

Comment: can you share your regex?

Comment: what happens when you reverse the order of the elements in the array ?

Comment: Have a look at using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php instead of replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your replace array by longest keyword first, so that it will be replaced first, and only later on replace shorter keys:

```php
$strings = ["1000-M", "1000-MA", "1000+MA-M", "MA/2", "M*MA+100"];

$replace = ['M' => '500', 'MA' => '200'];

krsort($replace);

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo $str . ':' . str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $str) . PHP_EOL;
}

// 1000-M => 1000-500
// 1000-MA => 1000-200
// 1000+MA-M => 1000+200-500
// MA/2 => 200/2
// M*MA+100 => 500*200+100
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=RY5BC4IwFMfPDfYdHhJMc9kSulQWOwQdGnmPkCErw0jZvEj03ZtT67L9_u_t_d62-7qoMcJoahr9eN0NJHDxloyxufAoDMRHDAXv64IvYnfPBA9tx7tunEWr-ilz1VmIIJDsgKwYIxSI4H2Mbewfl9pUuvHHmcAVb5VWMi_A_31IGug4gDdGE5UXlYsQAVkTe1rOBoMvtZZtVqrW_K0URqSDJ4L0mGaH88ku_GD0BQ%2C%2C&v=8.2.1)

Comment: Yeeeees, this works fantastic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace_callback()` function to match the variable names using regex.

```
foreach ($strings as &$str) {
  $str = preg_replace_callback('/\b(M|MA)\b/', function ($matches) use ($array) {
    return $array[$matches[1]];
  }, $str);
}
```

Comment: Will this work for `MAM` to be replaced to `200500`?

Comment: @Justinas No it will not work because it only matches `M` or `MA` as whole words.